# Scraping data with a lack of classes / ids on elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data to build an object which looks like;

```
{
    "artist": "Oasis",
        "albums": {
            "Definitely Maybe": [
                "Rock n Roll Star",
                "Shakermaker",
                ...
            ],

            "(What's The Story) Morning Glory": [
                "Hello",
                "Roll With It"
                ...
            ],
            ...
        }
}
```

[Here is how the HTML on the page looks;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH8Qs.png)

---

I'm currently scrapping the data like so;

```
data = []
for div in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"listAlbum"}):
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        if a.text.strip() is "":
            pass
        elif a.text.strip():
            data.append(a.text.strip())
```

Likewise, grabbing the album names is straightforward also;

```
for div in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"album"}):
    titles = div.findAll('b')
    for t in titles:
        ...
```

My problem is how to use the above two loops to build an object like the one at the top. How can I ensure the songs from X album, go into the correct album object. If each song had an `album` attribute, it would be clear to me. However, with the HTML structured the way it is - I'm at a bit of a loss.

**EDIT:** Find the HTML below;

```html
<div id="listAlbum">
  <a id="1368"></a>
  <div class="album">album: <b>"Definitely Maybe"</b> (1994)</div>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/rocknrollstar.html" target="_blank">Rock 'n' Roll Star</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/shakermaker.html" target="_blank">Shakermaker</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/liveforever.html" target="_blank">Live Forever</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/upinthesky.html" target="_blank">Up In The Sky</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/columbia.html" target="_blank">Columbia</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/supersonic.html" target="_blank">Supersonic</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/bringitondown.html" target="_blank">Bring It On Down</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/cigarettesalcohol.html" target="_blank">Cigarettes &amp; Alcohol</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/digsysdiner.html" target="_blank">Digsy's Diner</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/slideaway.html" target="_blank">Slide Away</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/marriedwithchildren.html" target="_blank">Married With Children</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/sadsong.html" target="_blank">Sad Song</a><br>

  <a id="1366"></a>
  <div class="album">album: <b>"(What's The Story) Morning Glory"</b> (1995)</div>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/hello.html" target="_blank">Hello</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/rollwithit.html" target="_blank">Roll With It</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/wonderwall.html" target="_blank">Wonderwall</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/dontlookbackinanger.html" target="_blank">Don't Look Back In Anger</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/heynow.html" target="_blank">Hey Now</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/somemightsay.html" target="_blank">Some Might Say</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/castnoshadow.html" target="_blank">Cast No Shadow</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/sheselectric.html" target="_blank">She's Electric</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/morningglory.html" target="_blank">Morning Glory</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/champagnesupernova.html" target="_blank">Champagne Supernova</a><br>
  <a href="../lyrics/oasis/boneheadsbankholiday.html" target="_blank">Bonehead's Bank Holiday</a><br>
```

Comment: Your provided screenshot is of no use and it is highly discouraged. Paste html elements instead.

Comment: Either paste all the required html elements in your question or provide the url that you are scraping.

Comment: Hi @KeyurPotdar, the page is here - https://www.azlyrics.com/o/oasis.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`find_next_siblings()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling).

Code:

```
oasis = {
    'artist': 'Oasis',
    'albums': {}
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')  # where html is the html you've provided
all_albums = soup.find('div', id='listAlbum')

first_album = all_albums.find('div', class_='album')
album_name = first_album.b.text
songs = []

for tag in first_album.find_next_siblings(['a', 'div']):
    # If tag is <div> add the previous album.
    if tag.name == 'div':
        oasis['albums'][album_name] = songs
        songs = []
        album_name = tag.b.text

    # If tag is <a> append song to the list.
    else:
        songs.append(tag.text)

# Add the last album
oasis['albums'][album_name] = songs

print(oasis)
```

Output:

```
{
    'artist': 'Oasis', 
    'albums': {
        '"Definitely Maybe"': ["Rock 'n' Roll Star", 'Shakermaker', 'Live Forever', 'Up In The Sky', 'Columbia', 'Supersonic', 'Bring It On Down', 'Cigarettes & Alcohol', "Digsy's Diner", 'Slide Away', 'Married With Children', 'Sad Song', ''], 
        '"(What\'s The Story) Morning Glory"': ['Hello', 'Roll With It', 'Wonderwall', "Don't Look Back In Anger", 'Hey Now', 'Some Might Say', 'Cast No Shadow', "She's Electric", 'Morning Glory', 'Champagne Supernova', "Bonehead's Bank Holiday"]
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

After checking the website, I've made a few changes to the code.

First, you need to skip this `<a id="6910"></a>` tag (which is located at the end of each album) as it will add a song with empty name. Second, the text `other songs:` is not located inside `<b>` tag; so it will raise an error with `album_name = tag.b.text`.

Doing the following changes will give you exactly what you need.

```
for tag in first_album.find_next_siblings(['a', 'div']):
    if tag.name == 'div':
        oasis['albums'][album_name] = songs
        songs = []
        album_name = tag.text if tag.text == 'other songs:' else tag.b.text
        continue
    if tag.get('id'):
        continue
    songs.append(tag.text)
```

Final output:

```
{
    'artist': 'Oasis', 
    'albums': {
        '"Definitely Maybe"': ["Rock 'n' Roll Star", 'Shakermaker', 'Live Forever', 'Up In The Sky', 'Columbia', 'Supersonic', 'Bring It On Down', 'Cigarettes & Alcohol', "Digsy's Diner", 'Slide Away', 'Married With Children', 'Sad Song'], 
        '"(What\'s The Story) Morning Glory"': ['Hello', 'Roll With It', 'Wonderwall', "Don't Look Back In Anger", 'Hey Now', 'Some Might Say', 'Cast No Shadow', "She's Electric", 'Morning Glory', 'Champagne Supernova', "Bonehead's Bank Holiday"], 
        '"Be Here Now"': ["D'You Know What I Mean?", 'My Big Mouth', 'Magic Pie', 'Stand By Me', 'I Hope, I Think, I Know', 'The Girl In The Dirty Shirt', 'Fade In-Out', "Don't Go Away", 'Be Here Now', 'All Around The World', "It's Getting Better (Man!!)"], 
        '"The Masterplan"': ['Acquiesce', 'Underneath The Sky', 'Talk Tonight', 'Going Nowhere', 'Fade Away', 'I Am The Walrus (Live)', 'Listen Up', "Rockin' Chair", 'Half The World Away', "(It's Good) To Be Free", 'Stay Young', 'Headshrinker', 'The Masterplan'], 
        '"Standing On The Shoulder Of Giants"': ["Fuckin' In The Bushes", 'Go Let It Out', 'Who Feels Love?', 'Put Yer Money Where Yer Mouth Is', 'Little James', 'Gas Panic!', 'Where Did It All Go Wrong?', 'Sunday Morning Call', 'I Can See A Liar', 'Roll It Over'], 
        '"Heathen Chemistry"': ['The Hindu Times', 'Force Of Nature', 'Hung In A Bad Place', 'Stop Crying Your Heart Out', 'Song Bird', 'Little By Little', '(Probably) All In The Mind', 'She Is Love', 'Born On A Different Cloud', 'Better Man'], 
        '"Don\'t Believe The Truth"': ['Turn Up The Sun', 'Mucky Fingers', 'Lyla', 'Love Like A Bomb', 'The Importance Of Being Idle', 'The Meaning Of Soul', "Guess God Thinks I'm Abel", 'Part Of The Queue', 'Keep The Dream Alive', 'A Bell Will Ring', 'Let There Be Love'], 
        '"Dig Out Your Soul"': ['Bag It Up', 'The Turning', 'Waiting For The Rapture', 'The Shock Of The Lightning', "I'm Outta Time", '(Get Off Your) High Horse Lady', 'Falling Down', "To Be Where There's Life", "Ain't Got Nothin'", 'The Nature Of Reality', 'Soldier On', 'I Believe In All'], 
        'other songs:': ["(As Long As They've Got) Cigarettes In Hell", '(I Got) The Fever', 'Alice', 'Alive', 'Angel Child', 'Boy With The Blues', 'Carry Us All', 'Cloudburst', 'Cum On Feel The Noize', "D'Yer Wanna Be A Spaceman", 'Eyeball Tickler', 'Flashbax', 'Full On', 'Helter Skelter', 'Heroes', 'I Will Believe', "Idler's Dream", 'If We Shadows', "It's Better People", 'Just Getting Older', "Let's All Make Believe", 'My Sister Lover', 'One Way Road', 'Round Are Way', 'Step Out', 'Street Fighting Man', 'Take Me', 'Take Me Away', 'The Fame', 'Whatever', "You've Got To Hide Your Love Away"]
    }
}
```